# HTML: remove a:hover for images?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, image, href

For **text** links, I have:

CSS:

```
a:link {color: #3366a9; text-decoration: none}
a:hover {border-bottom: 1px solid; color: black}
```

But this also adds a black underline on linkable **IMGs** that I do not want.

How do I remove the `border-bottom` on linkable IMGs when hovered using CSS?

I've tried the following:

```
a:hover img {border-bottom: 0px}
```

But that doesn't work

[Live example](http://www.uptownelite.com/find/?city=dallas%2C+tx)  (try to hover over the logo in top-left)

Comment: I just checked the live example, it works fine in Safari 4 Mac and IE 7 Windows.

Did you forget to mark this question as answered?

Comment: @rpflo, using Firefox 3.5RC and IE6 - the logo gets a black border when hovered over. Seems that only webkit does what's intended

Comment: Live example link requires logging in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you float your images vs. inline this will work and will require no modifications to image link attributes that Steve's answer requires.

```
a:hover img {
border: none !important;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
a:hover img {border-bottom: 0px;}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: he's assigned a rule to *anchors*, so stating something inside doesn't have a border wont affect the actual hover tag

Comment: I've linked to the live example in the main post above ... in case that helps.

Comment: Hmm, odd thing is that the bottom border only shows up in IE8.  Tested compaitibiliy mode (doesn't display any border) and Chrome 3.0 (works as expected).  Did specifying the :hover directly on a class for the image not work either?

Comment: To get this working in IE8, I added this below my a:hover in the css file:

img
{
 border: 0px;
}

Comment: @Relster, the bottom-border shows up for me using Firefox 3.5RC

Comment: @Relster, it appears the bottom-border also show in IE6 ... but webkit doesn't show it, so Chrome & Safari works.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't make sense for the site, but maybe it does: what about putting your main navigation links inside of a specific div and then making your css .mainnav a:hover {border-bottom: 1px;}.  Rather than using the bottom border everywhere and limiting the img, you're limiting the border to only where you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works:

```
    a:link {color: #3366a9; text-decoration: none}
    a:hover {border-bottom: 1px solid black; }

    .aimg:link {color: #3366a9; text-decoration: none}      
    .aimg:hover { border-bottom: none; }
```

Then set the anchors with images in them to the "aimg" class:

```
<a class="aimg" href="Test.htm"><img src="images/myimage.gif" /></a>
```

Comment: @seanmonstar, is the ">" selector effectively a "has"?

Comment: no, > means immediate child. div > a selects <div><a href="#">asdf</a></div> but not <div><p><a href="#">qwer</a></p></div>.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me also in IE. IE displayed the borders but with this it doesn't anymore.

```
a img {/*whatever you need*/
border: none !important;
}
a img:hover{/*whatever you need*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this example here: https://perishablepress.com/css-remove-link-underlines-borders-linked-images/

```
a[href$=jpg], a[href$=jpeg], a[href$=jpe], a[href$=png], a[href$=gif] {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0 none;
    }
```

This is exactly what you want I suppose.
Works perfect in Firefox, removes all effects from the link, which contains an image of given formats.

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery to add a "no-hover" class to all a tags that contain an image:

```
$('a > img').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('no-hover');
});
```

And in CSS i did this:

```
a.no-hover:hover {
  border-bottom: 0px
}
```

If jQuery is too heavy for you, you can use [picoQuery](http://picoquery.com). Its just 1k, if only you choose the .each() method.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `a img {border:none}` ?

Comment: I've linked to the live example in the main post above ... in case that helps.